# Error al instalar sqlite3 con npm desde termux (Android)

Tags: nodejs, npm, sqlite3

Soy un poco nuevo con *NodeJS* y con consola Linux, y lo que sucede es que escuché de una aplicación llamada **termux** la cual es una consola Linux la cual podría servirme para mi aprendizaje con *NodeJS*.

Intenté instalar **sqlite3** con *npm* usando `npm install sqlite3` y me salió este error:

> ```
> /data/data/com.termux/files/home/node/sqlite_example/node_modules/sqlite3
> > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
>
> node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(403):
> https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v3.1.13/node-v57-android-arm.tar.gz
> node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for sqlite3@3.1.13 and
> node@8.9.0 (node-v57 ABI) (falling back to source compile with
> node-gyp) gyp ERR! configure error gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find
> Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable. gyp
> ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython
> (/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:483:19)
> gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous>
> (/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:397:16)
> gyp ERR! stack     at F
> (/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:68:16)
> gyp ERR! stack     at E
> (/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
> gyp ERR! stack     at
> /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
> gyp ERR! stack     at
> /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
> gyp ERR! stack     at
> /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
> gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21) gyp ERR!
> System Linux 3.18.24-perf-g5f4c39b gyp ERR! command
> "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/node"
> "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js"
> "configure" "--fallback-to-build"
> "--module=/data/data/com.termux/files/home/node/sqlite_example/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v57-android-arm/node_sqlite3.node"
> "--module_name=node_sqlite3"
> "--module_path=/data/data/com.termux/files/home/node/sqlite_example/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v57-android-arm"
> gyp ERR! cwd
> /data/data/com.termux/files/home/node/sqlite_example/node_modules/sqlite3
> gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.0 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2 gyp ERR! not ok yp
> ERR! not ok node-pre-gyp ERR! build error node-pre-gyp ERR! stack
> Error: Failed to execute '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/node
> /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js
> configure --fallback-to-build
> --module=/data/data/com.termux/files/home/node/sqlite_example/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v57-android-arm/node_sqlite3.node
> --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=/data/data/com.termux/files/home/node/sqlite_example/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v57-android-arm'
> (1) node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous>
> (/data/data/com.termux/files/home/node/sqlite_example/node_modules/sqlite3/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
> node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13) node-pre-gyp
> ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7) node-pre-gyp
> ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
> node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
> (internal/child_process.js:209:5) node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux
> 3.18.24-perf-g5f4c39b node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/node"
> "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/node/sqlite_example/node_modules/sqlite3/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp"
> "install" "--fallback-to-build" node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd
> /data/data/com.termux/files/home/node/sqlite_example/node_modules/sqlite3
> node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.0 node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v
> v0.6.38 node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok Failed to execute
> '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/node
> /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js
> configure --fallback-to-build
> --module=/data/data/com.termux/files/home/node/sqlite_example/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v57-android-arm/node_sqlite3.node
> --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=/data/data/com.termux/files/home/node/sqlite_example/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v57-android-arm'
> (1) npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
> '/data/data/com.termux/files/home/node/sqlite_example/package.json'
> npm WARN sqlite_example No description npm WARN sqlite_example No
> repository field. npm WARN sqlite_example No README data npm WARN
> sqlite_example No license field.
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! sqlite3@3.1.13
> install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build` npm ERR! Exit
> status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the sqlite3@3.1.13 install
> script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is
> likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!    
> /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.npm/_logs/2017-11-08T18_30_17_349Z-debug.log
> ```

Estoy con las versiones: **Node v8. 9.0** y **Npm 5.5.1**

¿Alguna idea de como solucionarlo?

Muchas gracias :)

Answer (score 0):

Ya pude instalar sqlite3:

```
apt install libllvm
apt install clang make nodejs-dev libuv-dev
apt install g++
npm install sqlite3
```